# image slider javascript does weird stuff

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi im new to coding and have to finish an automatic image slider using javascript,html and css i can make a slider with arrow and a automatic one i just cant seem to put them together.
I did what w3schools dit bet a simplefied version and
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp)

and heres my attempt at getting an image slider with an automatic slider together.

```
let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
 
}

function showSlides(n) {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}   

  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
   
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    
  

}
 {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); 
}
```

HTML
`

```
<div class="mySlides">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="images/queri 1.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">queri 1</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="images/queri 2.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">queri 2</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="images/QUERI 3.png" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">queri 3</div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

</div>
<br>
```

`

the main problems are that the previeous button doesnt work when i ad the second part and when i use a button it starts skipping automaticly quicker i hope this is clear if not please tell mesry for my bad english

Comment: You have two functions named the same thing .. `function showSlides(n)` --  You need to remove the function you aren't using .. Or name it something different ..

Comment: i removed the second function show slides(n) this those make it a litle better but the autmoatice slider doesnt function anymore

Comment: You can also post your HTML codes so that we can take a look at it and see what's wrong. Also make sure to edit your question if it has a mistake especially the Javascript code.

Comment: i edited it and added html